# Creating a custom list class in C#

Tags: c#, list, class, dictionary

I want to create a class that is a Custom List. So I have done

```
 public class Set1 : List<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {

    public Set1() : base(List<Dictionary<string, string>>)         
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> mySet = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
        {
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"first_name","John"},
            },
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"last_name","Smith"},
            },

        };

        base(mySet);

    }
}
```

But this does not compile. What am I doing wrong please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Care to share the compiler error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why Dictionaries for both first and last name?

Comment: What do you need a new class for? A `List<Dictionary>` seems odd enough, but what implementation to you intend to add that `List<Dictionary>` doesn't already provide?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a base/alternate constructor from within the method in C# like you can in some other languages.

However, you don't need to call the base constructor in this case - you can just do:

```
public Set1()        
{
    this.Add(
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"first_name","John"},
        }
    );
    this.Add(
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"last_name","Smith"},
        }

    );
}
```

If you *really* want to call the base constructor, though, you'll have to inline the list creation in the declaration:

```
public Set1()        
 : base( new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"first_name","John"},
                },
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"last_name","Smith"},
                }
            }
        )
{
    // nothing more to do here
}
```

but that creates a list, only to have the constructor copy the items into the list, increasing your memory usage for a short time.

Comment: **No, the minimum the OP can do to make their wrong code compile is not the right answer.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you're looking for

```
new Dictionary<string, string>() {
          {"first_name","John"}, {"last_name","Smith"},
      }.
```

You don't have any need to inherit from List here. What you wanted was an instance of some collection. A class is a general template for data and behaviour, not something you define to hold the specific information for John.

Even better, create a class for the apprioriate thing (a person), and create an instance of a `List<Person>`

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Forename {get;set;}
        public string Surname {get;set;}
    }

    ///

    var people = new List<Person>() { new Person("John", "Smith") };
```